# How to reduce latency with openssh?

Tags: ssh, osx-leopard, openssh, latency

I'm ssh-ing to a server several thousands kilometers away, and every keystroke takes 500-800ms, so it is getting annoying.

Is it possible to have my ssh client cache each line I type locally and only send to the other server when I press return?

Comment: This would be job of your terminal emulator (Terminal.app or something), not the SSH client. Unfortunately, all I can find about local line editing is an option in Windows' PuTTY. For now, try `printf '\e[12l'; stty -echo` to enable local _echo_ (and `printf '\e[12h'; stty echo` to disable it). This will still send each keypress separately, but will echo them locally, resulting in instant updates and epic confusion (really).

Comment: FWIW, check your Internet connection. I SSH to machines which are ~1700 km, ~7000 km, ~8000 km away, with less than 200 ms RTT – even though my connection is barely above dialup. (Admittedly, I did my tests _without_ BitTorrent running.)

Comment: grawity: I just checked the distance, it is ~15200 km. Can I still achieve latency < 200ms?

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of a tool like [Mosh](https://mosh.org)

From Mosh site:

1. Remote terminal application that allows roaming, supports intermittent connectivity, and provides intelligent local echo and line editing of user keystrokes.
2. Mosh is a replacement for SSH. It's more robust and responsive, especially over Wi-Fi, cellular, and long-distance links.
3. Mosh is free software, available for GNU/Linux, BSD, macOS, Solaris, Android, Chrome, and iOS

Answer (score 4):

See the Compression (-C) option in *man 1 ssh*. It may help on your circumstance.

A better question would be "What's the round-trip latency of my connection?," which you can determine by looking at the round-trip time (RTT) via ping. Take a close look at the -s, -M, and -U options (see *man 8 ping*) to enable you to adjust your packets to see if the problem is dropped packets, or some other aspect of your network connection.

Distance can certainly play a factor on certain types of networks (DSL or satellite, for example) but has much more to do with network type, network congestion, and other factors that you haven't mentioned in your post.

Lastly, don't discount server or host issues. Try [testing your connection](http://speedtest.net/) against various servers to see if you have a problem that's limited to a single host, or if your issue is more generic.